# Implementing M3 in RascalMPL

Tags: rascal

How can I implement an M3 model (relation & AST) for any language, I have looked at the "M3: A General Model for Source Code Analytics in Rascal" and I get the gist of it but how can I actually implement one (for let's say SQL). Also any resource would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, [that M3 paper](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Ejurgenv/papers/SWAN2015.pdf) is the high level description of the design.

How to implement a new one, depends on both your source data and what kind of language you want to model. Sometimes we recover all data using Rascal, sometimes we use an existing library/parser to recover the data.

An example is the [ClaiR - C Language Analysis in Rascal](https://github.com/usethesource/clair) m3 library. Which uses the eclipse cdt for most of the data.

Comment: Thanks @davy, so based on your recommendation I could also use a parser written in rascal, most of the examples I have seen so far use eclipse cdt. How can I implement the same thing with a parser I built in rascal?